# What is difference between "loath" and "loathe"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I am learning English. I have read these two words and according to dictionary there meaning is almost same. but I don't know what is actual difference between them. Please elaborate these words using some sentences.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loathe is a verb meaning

> to hate someone or something

Example:

> From an early age the brothers have loathed each other.

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loathe)

Loath is an adjective meaning

> to be unwilling to do something

Example:

> I'm loath to spend it all at once.

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loath)

To summarize, the two words are used in different parts of the sentence, and the verb (loathe) expresses a much stronger negative emotion compared to the adjective (loath).

Comment: Wow. I have never, ever heard of loath before. The more you know.